# Load product default view

Tags: magento-1.9, product, multistore

Currently when editing a product in a specific store view, I am getting the product like this:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($magento_product_id);
```

Instead, I would like to edit a product's default values. Am I correct when assuming that's done just by removing the storeid like this?

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($magento_product_id);
```

Answer (score 6):

yes you can remove the store id like you mentioned

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($magento_product_id);
```

or you can use 0 (zero) as the store id:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(0)->load($magento_product_id);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Just wanted to make sure before I started using it in a live store..